# Sorting SortedList in descending order C#

Tags: c#, sorting, collections

I have

```
SortedList<string, object> testIds = new SortedList<string, object>();
```

And I neet it sort in descending order. 
I used for sorting next construction:

```
testIds.ToList().Sort(delegate(KeyValuePair<string, object>x, KeyValuePair<string, object>y)
{
     return x.Key.CompareTo(y.Key)*-1;
});
```

But it did not help me.Can you give me some advice how to solve this problem?

Comment: I'd use [OrderByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534855(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I tried to use it too. But it also didn't work in my case.

Comment: "it didn't work" is not enough information to diagnose a problem, and you did not mention this in the question.

Comment: you are creating a list, calling Sort and then you are throwing away that list.

Comment: testIds.Add("2",null);
testIds.Add("1",null);
testIds.Add("4", null);

Comment: @Mykhalik `testIds.OrderByDescending(t=>t.Key)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although `SortedList<K,V>` sorts in ascending order by default, it provides a constructor that takes a custom `IComparer<K>` that lets you switch the order to whatever you need.

Implement `IComparer<string>` that inverts the result of the regular comparison, and give it to the constructor of `SortedList<K,V>`:

```
class ReverseComparer : IComparer<string> {
    public int Compare(string x, string y) {
        return -x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}

var testIds = new SortedList<string,object>(new ReverseComparer());
```

You can write the same thing in a single line, without making a named class for it:

```
var testIds = new SortedList<string,object>(
    // Note how the negation is replaced with reversing the order of comparison
    Comparer<string>.Create((x, y) => y.CompareTo(x))
);
```

Comment: @dcastro Thanks for the comment! I usually do both these things, but I provided an explicit implementation of an interface to eliminate the sense of "magic", and used explicit negation to mimic OP's comparison logic, where he multiplies the result by `-1`.

Comment: Late comment, but note that by reversing using the comparer, you will reverse the Min and Max. Better to think of these as Head/Tail.

Answer (score 8):

As pointed out by dasblinkenlight, you should use the constructor overload that takes an `IComparer<T>`.

However, if this is a one time thing, you're better off using `Comparer<T>.Create`, instead of creating a whole new class just for this.

```
var comparer = Comparer<string>.Create((x, y) => y.CompareTo(x)); 

var testIds = new SortedList<string,object>(comparer);
```

Also, when comparing items in reverse order, the convention is to compare `y` with `x`, instead of comparing `x` with `y` and inverting the result.

Comment: Upvoted. Just what I wanted to say! Use `Comparer<>.Create`, and do not rely on negating an integer. Remember that if `CompareTo` happens to return `int.MinValue` (which is unusual but legal), then the return value and the negated return value are the same!

Answer (score -1):

Just use Reverse. Let's suppose you have a orderedlist OrigOrderedList, then

```
SortedList<string, object> testIds = OrigOrderedList.Reverse() // should do the work

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      SortedList<string, object> test1 = new SortedList<string, object>();
      test1.Add("a", "A");
      test1.Add("b", "B");
      test1.Add("c", "C");
      Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", test1.Select(x => x.Key)));
      Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", test1.Reverse().Select(x => x.Key)));
    }
```

Comment: This negates the whole purpose of even having a `SortedList`. You'll have to rearrange it every time a new item is added.

Comment: Correct. this is just a sample to show something on the screen.

Comment: @i100 Can I get SortedList type of collection after sort in descending order?

Comment: depend on what constructor did you use. the @dcastro sample will do it.